# Heatmaply Remove Ticks

Tags: r, heatmaply

I have the following code:

```
colorStand <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("blue", "white", "red"))

heatmaply(data, margins = c(60,100,40,20), colors=colorStand,
    limits = c(-2.5,2.5),showticklabels = c(T,F))
```

This doesn't show row labels (which is good), however I still have ticks, does anyone know how to remove them?

Thanks

Comment: This is not currently possible, but I've added it as an "issue", and we'll see if we can do it: https://github.com/talgalili/heatmaply/issues/102

Answer (score 3):

This is now resolved, thanks for the bug report: 
https://github.com/talgalili/heatmaply/commit/50bea348ff8887429c2df431e3cc38beb5a0def7